# Disable authorisation on preflight OPTIONS request in HAProxy

Tags: authentication, http, haproxy, cors

We have a HAProxy setup which has basic auth on some of our backends. We now want to enable CORS requests to our backends but this is failing for those with basic auth enabled.
When CORS makes it preflight OPTIONS request it does not include the auth header and thus it fails and so the request fails.

Is there a way of allowing the OPTIONS request without authrisation but mandating it for all other requests?

Our haproxy.cfg has the following sections relevant to this:

```
#User lists used to enforce HTTP Basic Authentication
...
userlist ul_hyknpj6tb-uakf5isp
  user fred password $6$H/M21cSsvXn$jlEZQV7QL/clhV7JtZkAQf34QAPfZq5sE.zLE.M3gi4K1DV5J6ppc.e1JAOP0CtVxM0.n157llg5tsTp0gPFj1
....
backend b_term_hyknpj6tb-uakf5isp
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  stick-table type ip size 1k expire 30s store bytes_in_rate(1s),bytes_out_rate(1s)
  tcp-request content track-sc2 src
  tcp-request inspect-delay 200ms
  tcp-request content accept if ! too_many_req
  tcp-request content accept if WAIT_END  
  rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=16000000;\ includeSubDomains
  acl is_auth http_auth(ul_hyknpj6tb-uakf5isp)
  http-request auth realm iiboc if !is_auth
  server node_hyknpj6tb-uakf5isp_1000 192.31.11.70:7843 check ssl verify required crt fred/fred-internal.pem ca-file bob/bob-internal.cert.pem 
.....
```

Comment: Which HAProxy version are you using?

Comment: HA-Proxy version 1.5.14

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the OPTIONS request without authorization by handling those requests in a different backend that does not require authenticatoin:

```
frontend fe_main
    acl options_method method OPTIONS
    use_backend be_options if options_method
```

Where **be_options** is a backend similar to **b_term_hyknpj6tb-uakf5isp** but without *http-request auth realm iiboc if !is_auth*